# Days/Months between to Dates(only Year/Month)

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I need to calculate days and month between two start dates.

E.g. I have two Dates 1.1.2012 and 30.4.2012 and now I want to know the amount of days and months which are included in this range.

The result should be 121 days and 4 months. What I get instead is 120 days and 3 months.

What is the best approach to start here with joda time?

My code (both dates are java.util.Date):

```
Months.monthsBetween(new DateMidnight(startDate), new DateMidnight(endDate)).getMonths();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00, 00);
  DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2012, 4, 30, 00, 00, 00, 00);
  System.out.println(Days.daysIn(new Interval(dt1, dt2)));     // 120D
  System.out.println(Months.monthsIn(new Interval(dt1, dt2))); // 3M
```

Diff between dt1 and dt2 in months is **3 full month** - it's true. There should not be 4 months

Diff between dt1 and dt2 in days is (31 days + 29 days + 31 days + 29 days) = **120 days**. 30th day - 30.04.2012 isn't finished yet, so it's not full day.

So *The result should be 121 days and 4 months* - wrong hypothesis.
**The result should be 120 days and 3 months**

Comment: I dont understand if I have the months from January to April its 4. January, February, March and April. Maybe my approach is the wrong one or I am using the wrong method

Comment: April not finished yet at 'April 30th'. April finished at 'May 1st'